# MVCMailer Scaffolding not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I used NuGet Package Manager to install MVCMailer in VS2012 Express Web - and got a green tick, to indicate it had installed correctly.

However, when trying to setup a template/view, using the Scaffold command, I see the following:

```
PM> Scaffold Mailer.Razor UserMailer BookingUpdate
Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that
accepts argument 'UserMailer'.
At line:1 char:9
+ Scaffold <<<<  Mailer.Razor UserMailer BookingUpdate
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder],
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,
T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more research, I installed T4Scaffold - and restarted VS - and it worked.  I hope this helps someone else.

Mark